# Activate arc lighter with Arduino

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, mosfet, resistors, circuit-design

I have a [SaberLight plasma arc lighter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EII2HM8), and I have taken it apart for a flamethrower project. I would like to use an Arduino Uno to programmatically activate the arc lighter. Using the Arduino Uno, what is the best method in order to activate the arc lighter?

My initial hunch is to remove the button (pictured), and connect one of the wires to a resistor which feeds into one of the Arduinio pins, whereas the other other wire connects to the Arduino ground. Is this correct? If so, how would I know what resistance value to use?

I would test my hunch, but do not want to break the lighter necessarily.

[image: My arc-lighter taken apart]

The attached battery states that the voltage is 3.7V and the current is 180mAh

Comment: How about we get to see a complete schematic of this device? To the better ability you have of producing one....

Comment: Do you have a multimeter? if you do, set it to DC volts and connect the probes to the terminals on the switch (mark which wire is connected to the black probe). Record the voltage, including the polarity. Next, set the multimeter to Dc mA and connect the probes to the switch (this should activate the arc as if you'd pressed the switch). Record the amperage. Then go back and edit your post to add these readings.

Comment: You’d be better off using a relay or optocoupler as this removes some constraints in needing to know what the actual circuit of the ‘lighter’ is.

Comment: "Best" is pretty subjective. Most likely you don't want the best but cheapest and simplest way possible. If there are no specs how the arc lighter operates normally then it is hard to suggest how to automate it. If you don't know how it works, randomly connecting the button wires to Arduino pins can damage the Arduino or the lighter or both. For all we know, the button might just connect the battery to the circuit to activate it, so it may require a lot of current.

Comment: Two things: 
1. I actually don't have the physical advice, it is on its way through amazon and will arrive tomorrow. The image above is a screenshot of the exact lighter I'm using, so I will not be able to provide current/votlage of the system at present. For the sake of answers, would it be possible to just assume the current is X and voltage is Y, then I can solve for these values later?

Comment: 2. I'm genuinely curious as to what the high level plan would be in this case? Would I solder the button wires together, but then replace the battery with the Arduino and use that Arduino to actuate power? OR would I keep their battery, but instead place my Arduino where the button currently is and actuate power from there? The first option makes mores sense to me because, in the third option, there would be like 2 separate power sources.

Comment: You’re trying to hack a device to do something it was not designed to do. The manufacturer does not give you schematics or specifications to allow you to make decisions on how to hack it, so you need to reverse engineer the circuit and make measurements to gain critical information. Once you know how many volts/amps are required then you can make an informed decision otherwise its just guessing.

Comment: Okay Kartman, I found the voltage and amperage :) Any thoughts now?